# FreeRADIUS radclient tagged attribute syntax

Tags: freeradius, radius

Although it's not commonly used in RADIUS Access-Requests, I want to send a 'tag' along with Tunnel-Private-Group-ID attribute using FreeRADIUS radclient. Tags are defined in RFC2868 and seem to be mentioned in /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.rfc2868

`ATTRIBUTE       Tunnel-Private-Group-Id                 81      string  has_tag`

An example of a valid use-case is when a Cisco access switch has been configured to send the VLAN-ID of the requesting interface along with the Access-Request. The RADIUS server can use that additional attribute in its authorization logic.

The challenge I have is finding the radclient syntax to specify the tag ID octet.

In the example below I am sending attribute 81 (Tunnel-Private-Group-ID) in its usual string form.

`echo "User-Name = '00-00-00-00-00-02',User-Password = '00-00-00-00-00-02',NAS-IP-Address = 172.16.0.50,Packet-Src-IP-Address = 172.16.0.50,Calling-Station-ID = '00:00:00:00:00:02',Tunnel-Private-Group-ID='99'"| /usr/bin/radclient -x 172.6.0.100:1812 auth cisco123`

But that does not include the 1 octet tag value - is it possible to include that? And this is not a vendor specific thing - it's from the RFC2868 dictionary - I just happened to mention a use-case with Cisco switches.